# Magento 1.4.1 category filter

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have to show the list of products added to a particular category on ajax request. So when i tried to use category filter method it shows fatal error. Using magento 1.4.1

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'e.category_ids'
>   in 'where clause'' in
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace:
>    #0
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>    #1
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>    #2
>    /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)  >
>     #3
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT
>   count(DI...', Array)
>    #4
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT
>   count(DI...', Array)
>    #5
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(799):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT
>   count(DI...', Array)
>    #6
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(210):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne('SELECT count(DI...', Array)
>    #7
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Varien/Data/Collec
>   in
>   /var/www/html/wc2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 234

This is the code i added on ajax file

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addPriceData()       
->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>'604'))
->addCategoryFilter('category_id','604')
->setPageSize($limit)
->setPage($p, $limit)       
->addAttributeToSelect('*');



$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->setPageSize($limit)
   ->setPage($p, $limit)    
   ->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>'66,67'));
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
    echo $_product->getId();
endforeach;
```

Neither of them working. Both of them showing same error. Please someone help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(604);

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addPriceData()       
->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
->addCategoryFilter($category)
->setPageSize($limit)
->setPage($p, $limit)       
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

This filter should work.